# How to allow only positive value in a JSpinner?

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I want to allow only positive value in my `JSpinner`. How could I set it in Netbeans?

I tried in the properties of the spinner by choosing model and then the method call and after I don't know how to continue the modification.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using a [`SpinnerNumberModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html) as your model, just set the minimum value to 0.

(If you're not, you need to provide more details.)

Comment: no i'm not using SpinnerNumberModel but i tried to add it int the property of my jSpinner in Netbeans but i can't see anywhere where to set the minimum value there..Thank you